# Interpreting this raw text - a strategy?

Tags: ruby, parsing, text, language-agnostic, screen-scraping

I have this raw text:

```
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Pos Car  Competitor/Team                Driver                   Vehicle              Cap   CL Laps     Race.Time Fastest...Lap

1     6  Jason Clements                 Jason Clements           BMW M3               3200       10     9:48.5710   3 0:57.3228*
2    42  David Skillender               David Skillender         Holden VS Commodore  6000       10     9:55.6866   2 0:57.9409 
3    37  Bruce Cook                     Bruce Cook               Ford  Escort         3759       10     9:56.4388   4 0:58.3359 
4    18  Troy Marinelli                 Troy Marinelli           Nissan  Silvia       3396       10     9:56.7758   2 0:58.4443 
5    75  Anthony Gilbertson             Anthony Gilbertson       BMW M3               3200       10    10:02.5842   3 0:58.9336 
6    26  Trent Purcell                  Trent Purcell            Mazda RX7            2354       10    10:07.6285   4 0:59.0546 
7    12  Scott Hunter                   Scott Hunter             Toyota  Corolla      2000       10    10:11.3722   5 0:59.8921 
8    91  Graeme Wilkinson               Graeme Wilkinson         Ford  Escort         2000       10    10:13.4114   5 1:00.2175 
9     7  Justin Wade                    Justin Wade              BMW M3               4000       10    10:18.2020   9 1:00.8969 
10   55  Greg Craig                     Grag Craig               Toyota  Corolla      1840       10    10:18.9956   7 1:00.7905 
11   46  Kyle Orgam-Moore               Kyle Organ-Moore         Holden VS Commodore  6000       10    10:30.0179   3 1:01.6741 
12   39  Uptiles Strathpine             Trent Spencer            BMW Mini Cooper S    1500       10    10:40.1436   2 1:02.2728 
13  177  Mark Hyde                      Mark Hyde                Ford  Escort         1993       10    10:49.5920   2 1:03.8069 
14   34  Peter Draheim                  Peter Draheim            Mazda RX3            2600       10    10:50.8159  10 1:03.4396 
15    5  Scott Douglas                  Scott Douglas            Datsun  1200         1998        9     9:48.7808   3 1:01.5371 
16   72  Paul Redman                    Paul Redman              Ford  Focus          2lt         9    10:11.3707   2 1:05.8729 
17    8  Matthew Speakman               Matthew Speakman         Toyota  Celica       1600        9    10:16.3159   3 1:05.9117 
18   74  Lucas Easton                   Lucas Easton             Toyota  Celica       1600        9    10:16.8050   6 1:06.0748 
19   77  Dean Fuller                    Dean Fuller              Mitsubishi  Sigma    2600        9    10:25.2877   3 1:07.3991 
20   16  Brett Batterby                 Brett Batterby           Toyota  Corolla      1600        9    10:29.9127   4 1:07.8420 
21   95  Ross Hurford                   Ross Hurford             Toyota  Corolla      1600        8     9:57.5297   2 1:12.2672 
DNF  13  Charles Wright                 Charles Wright           BMW 325i             2700        9     9:47.9888   7 1:03.2808 
DNF  20  Shane Satchwell                Shane Satchwell          Datsun  1200 Coupe   1998        1     1:05.9100   1 1:05.9100 

Fastest Lap Av.Speed Is 152kph, Race Av.Speed Is 148kph
R=under lap record by greatest margin, r=under lap record, *=fastest lap time
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Issue# 2 - Printed Sat May 26 15:43:31 2012                     Timing System By NATSOFT (03)63431311 www.natsoft.com.au/results
Amended
```

I need to parse it into an object with the obvious Position, Car, Driver etc fields. The issue is I have no idea on what sort of strategy to use. If I split it on whitespace, I would end up with a list like so:

```
["1", "6", "Jason", "Clements", "Jason", "Clements", "BMW", "M3", "3200", "10", "9:48.5710", "3", "0:57.3228*"]
```

Can you see the issue. I cannot just interpret this list, because people may have just 1 name, or 3 words in a name, or many different words in a car. It makes it impossible to just reference the list using indexes alone.

What about using the offsets defined by the column names? I can't quite see how that could be used though.

**Edit**: So the current algorithm I am using works like this:

1. Split the text on new line giving a collection of lines.
2. Find the common whitespace characters FURTHEST RIGHT on each line. I.e. the positions (indexes) on each line where every other
   line contains whitespace. EG:
3. Split the lines based on those common characters.
4. Trim the lines

Several issues exist:

If the names contain the same lengths like so:

```
Jason Adams
Bobby Sacka
Jerry Louis
```

Then it will interpret that as two separate items: ([`"Jason" "Adams", "Bobby", "Sacka", "Jerry", "Louis"]`).

Whereas if they all differed like so:

```
Dominic Bou
Bob Adams
Jerry Seinfeld
```

Then it would correctly split on the last 'd' in Seinfeld (and thus we'd get a collection of three names(`["Dominic Bou", "Bob Adams", "Jerry Seinfeld"]`).

It's also quite brittle. I am looking for a nicer solution.

Comment: What tools are available to you?  Unix (sed/awk/cut, etc.)?  I think Unix's cut would handle this nicely.

Comment: Ruby, but anything cut can do it can do (albeit it might be more painful).

Comment: Why not just split on Two spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `fixed_width` gem.

Your given file can be parsed with the following code:

```
require 'fixed_width'
require 'pp'

FixedWidth.define :cars do |d|
  d.head do |head|
    head.trap { |line| line !~ /\d/ }
  end
  d.body do |body|
    body.trap { |line| line =~ /^(\d|DNF)/ }
    body.column :pos, 4
    body.column :car, 5
    body.column :competitor, 31
    body.column :driver, 25
    body.column :vehicle, 21
    body.column :cap, 5
    body.column :cl_laps, 11
    body.column :race_time, 11
    body.column :fast_lap_no, 4
    body.column :fast_lap_time, 10
  end
end

pp FixedWidth.parse(File.open("races.txt"), :cars)
```

The `trap` method identifies the lines in each section. I used regex:

- The `head` regex looks for lines that don't contain a digit.
- The `body` regex looks for lines starting with a digit or "DNF"

Each section must include the line immediately after the last. The `column` definitions simply identify the number of columns to grab. The library strips whitespace for you. If you wanted to *produce* a fixed-width file, you can add alignment parameters, but it doesn't appear you will need that.

The result is a hash that starts like this:

```
{:head=>[{}, {}, {}],
 :body=>
  [{:pos=>"1",
    :car=>"6",
    :competitor=>"Jason Clements",
    :driver=>"Jason Clements",
    :vehicle=>"BMW M3",
    :cap=>"3200",
    :cl_laps=>"10",
    :race_time=>"9:48.5710",
    :fast_lap_no=>"3",
    :fast_lap_time=>"0:57.3228"},
   {:pos=>"2",
    :car=>"42",
    :competitor=>"David Skillender",
    :driver=>"David Skillender",
    :vehicle=>"Holden VS Commodore",
    :cap=>"6000",
    :cl_laps=>"10",
    :race_time=>"9:55.6866",
    :fast_lap_no=>"2",
    :fast_lap_time=>"0:57.9409"},
```

Answer (score 6):

This is not a good case for regex, you really want to discover the format and then unpack the lines:

```
lines = str.split "\n"

# you know the field names so you can use them to find the column positions
fields = ['Pos', 'Car', 'Competitor/Team', 'Driver', 'Vehicle', 'Cap', 'CL Laps', 'Race.Time', 'Fastest...Lap']
header = lines.shift until header =~ /^Pos/
positions = fields.map{|f| header.index f}

# use that to construct an unpack format string
format = 1.upto(positions.length-1).map{|x| "A#{positions[x] - positions[x-1]}"}.join
# A4A5A31A25A21A6A12A10

lines.each do |line|
  next unless line =~ /^(\d|DNF)/ # skip lines you're not interested in
  data = line.unpack(format).map{|x| x.strip}
  puts data.join(', ')
  # or better yet...
  car = Hash[fields.zip data]
  puts car['Driver']
end
```

Comment: That's not what I meant. You're taking this way to personally. The thing is, we have the same solution, but I regard the data formatting as a rule, you do not. And we can agree to disagree on that.

Comment: I claimed "**Unless there's a clear rule on how the columns are separated**, you can't really do it.". You, in your answer, assume there is a separation between the columns. It's basic logic.

Comment: The claim that no solution exists is **conditioned** by the fact that there is no rule in the column separation.

Answer (score 6):

http://blog.ryanwood.com/past/2009/6/12/slither-a-dsl-for-parsing-fixed-width-text-files this may solve your problem.

[here](https://github.com/ryanwood/slither) are few more examples and github.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. This... sort of works. It's tedious, but it does work at the moment. I'm still holding out for something better.

Comment: If width is fixed you could look at ruby string's `String#unpack` method. I couldn't find an example in ruby but here is something similar in perl http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html#Packing-Text there's

Answer (score 5):

I think it is easy enough to just use the fixed width on each line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# ruby parsing_winner.rb winners_list.txt 
args = ARGV
puts "ruby parsing_winner.rb winners_list.txt " if args.empty?
winner_file = open args.shift
array_of_race_results, array_of_race_results_array  = [], []

class RaceResult

  attr_accessor :position, :car, :team, :driver, :vehicle, :cap, :cl_laps, :race_time, :fastest, :fastest_lap
  def initialize(position, car, team, driver, vehicle, cap, cl_laps, race_time, fastest, fastest_lap)
    @position    = position 
    @car         = car 
    @team        = team  
    @driver      = driver  
    @vehicle     = vehicle  
    @cap         = cap  
    @cl_laps     = cl_laps  
    @race_time   = race_time 
    @fastest     = fastest
    @fastest_lap = fastest_lap 
  end

  def to_a
    # ["1", "6", "Jason", "Clements", "Jason", "Clements", "BMW", "M3", "3200", "10", "9:48.5710", "3", "0:57.3228*"]
    [position, car, team, driver, vehicle, cap, cl_laps, race_time, fastest, fastest_lap]
  end
end

# Pos Car  Competitor/Team                Driver                   Vehicle              Cap   CL Laps     Race.Time Fastest...Lap

# 1     6  Jason Clements                 Jason Clements           BMW M3               3200       10     9:48.5710   3 0:57.3228*
# 2    42  David Skillender               David Skillender         Holden VS Commodore  6000       10     9:55.6866   2 0:57.9409
# etc...
winner_file.each_line do |line|
  next if line[/^____/] || line[/^\w{4,}|^\s|^Pos/] || line[0..3][/\=/]
  position    = line[0..3].strip
  car         = line[4..8].strip
  team        = line[9..39].strip
  driver      = line[40..64].strip
  vehicle     = line[65..85].strip
  cap         = line[86..91].strip
  cl_laps     = line[92..101].strip
  race_time   = line[102..113].strip
  fastest     = line[114..116].strip
  fastest_lap = line[117..-1].strip
  racer = RaceResult.new(position, car, team, driver, vehicle, cap, cl_laps, race_time, fastest, fastest_lap)
  array_of_race_results << racer
  array_of_race_results_array << racer.to_a
end

puts "Race Results Objects: #{array_of_race_results}"
puts "Race Results: #{array_of_race_results_array.inspect}"
```

Output =>

```
Race Results Objects: [#<RaceResult:0x007fcc4a84b7c8 @position="1", @car="6", @team="Jason Clements", @driver="Jason Clements", @vehicle="BMW M3", @cap="3200", @cl_laps="10", @race_time="9:48.5710", @fastest="3", @fastest_lap="0:57.3228*">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4a84aa08 @position="2", @car="42", @team="David Skillender", @driver="David Skillender", @vehicle="Holden VS Commodore", @cap="6000", @cl_laps="10", @race_time="9:55.6866", @fastest="2", @fastest_lap="0:57.9409">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4a849ce8 @position="3", @car="37", @team="Bruce Cook", @driver="Bruce Cook", @vehicle="Ford  Escort", @cap="3759", @cl_laps="10", @race_time="9:56.4388", @fastest="4", @fastest_lap="0:58.3359">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4a8491f8 @position="4", @car="18", @team="Troy Marinelli", @driver="Troy Marinelli", @vehicle="Nissan  Silvia", @cap="3396", @cl_laps="10", @race_time="9:56.7758", @fastest="2", @fastest_lap="0:58.4443">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b091ab8 @position="5", @car="75", @team="Anthony Gilbertson", @driver="Anthony Gilbertson", @vehicle="BMW M3", @cap="3200", @cl_laps="10", @race_time="10:02.5842", @fastest="3", @fastest_lap="0:58.9336">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b0916a8 @position="6", @car="26", @team="Trent Purcell", @driver="Trent Purcell", @vehicle="Mazda RX7", @cap="2354", @cl_laps="10", @race_time="10:07.6285", @fastest="4", @fastest_lap="0:59.0546">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b091298 @position="7", @car="12", @team="Scott Hunter", @driver="Scott Hunter", @vehicle="Toyota  Corolla", @cap="2000", @cl_laps="10", @race_time="10:11.3722", @fastest="5", @fastest_lap="0:59.8921">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b090e88 @position="8", @car="91", @team="Graeme Wilkinson", @driver="Graeme Wilkinson", @vehicle="Ford  Escort", @cap="2000", @cl_laps="10", @race_time="10:13.4114", @fastest="5", @fastest_lap="1:00.2175">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b090a78 @position="9", @car="7", @team="Justin Wade", @driver="Justin Wade", @vehicle="BMW M3", @cap="4000", @cl_laps="10", @race_time="10:18.2020", @fastest="9", @fastest_lap="1:00.8969">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b090668 @position="10", @car="55", @team="Greg Craig", @driver="Grag Craig", @vehicle="Toyota  Corolla", @cap="1840", @cl_laps="10", @race_time="10:18.9956", @fastest="7", @fastest_lap="1:00.7905">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b090258 @position="11", @car="46", @team="Kyle Orgam-Moore", @driver="Kyle Organ-Moore", @vehicle="Holden VS Commodore", @cap="6000", @cl_laps="10", @race_time="10:30.0179", @fastest="3", @fastest_lap="1:01.6741">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b08fe48 @position="12", @car="39", @team="Uptiles Strathpine", @driver="Trent Spencer", @vehicle="BMW Mini Cooper S", @cap="1500", @cl_laps="10", @race_time="10:40.1436", @fastest="2", @fastest_lap="1:02.2728">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b08fa38 @position="13", @car="177", @team="Mark Hyde", @driver="Mark Hyde", @vehicle="Ford  Escort", @cap="1993", @cl_laps="10", @race_time="10:49.5920", @fastest="2", @fastest_lap="1:03.8069">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b08f628 @position="14", @car="34", @team="Peter Draheim", @driver="Peter Draheim", @vehicle="Mazda RX3", @cap="2600", @cl_laps="10", @race_time="10:50.8159", @fastest="10", @fastest_lap="1:03.4396">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b08f218 @position="15", @car="5", @team="Scott Douglas", @driver="Scott Douglas", @vehicle="Datsun  1200", @cap="1998", @cl_laps="9", @race_time="9:48.7808", @fastest="3", @fastest_lap="1:01.5371">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b08ee08 @position="16", @car="72", @team="Paul Redman", @driver="Paul Redman", @vehicle="Ford  Focus", @cap="2lt", @cl_laps="9", @race_time="10:11.3707", @fastest="2", @fastest_lap="1:05.8729">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b08e9f8 @position="17", @car="8", @team="Matthew Speakman", @driver="Matthew Speakman", @vehicle="Toyota  Celica", @cap="1600", @cl_laps="9", @race_time="10:16.3159", @fastest="3", @fastest_lap="1:05.9117">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b08e5e8 @position="18", @car="74", @team="Lucas Easton", @driver="Lucas Easton", @vehicle="Toyota  Celica", @cap="1600", @cl_laps="9", @race_time="10:16.8050", @fastest="6", @fastest_lap="1:06.0748">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b08e1d8 @position="19", @car="77", @team="Dean Fuller", @driver="Dean Fuller", @vehicle="Mitsubishi  Sigma", @cap="2600", @cl_laps="9", @race_time="10:25.2877", @fastest="3", @fastest_lap="1:07.3991">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4b08ddc8 @position="20", @car="16", @team="Brett Batterby", @driver="Brett Batterby", @vehicle="Toyota  Corolla", @cap="1600", @cl_laps="9", @race_time="10:29.9127", @fastest="4", @fastest_lap="1:07.8420">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4a848348 @position="21", @car="95", @team="Ross Hurford", @driver="Ross Hurford", @vehicle="Toyota  Corolla", @cap="1600", @cl_laps="8", @race_time="9:57.5297", @fastest="2", @fastest_lap="1:12.2672">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4a847948 @position="DNF", @car="13", @team="Charles Wright", @driver="Charles Wright", @vehicle="BMW 325i", @cap="2700", @cl_laps="9", @race_time="9:47.9888", @fastest="7", @fastest_lap="1:03.2808">, #<RaceResult:0x007fcc4a847010 @position="DNF", @car="20", @team="Shane Satchwell", @driver="Shane Satchwell", @vehicle="Datsun  1200 Coupe", @cap="1998", @cl_laps="1", @race_time="1:05.9100", @fastest="1", @fastest_lap="1:05.9100">]
Race Results: [["1", "6", "Jason Clements", "Jason Clements", "BMW M3", "3200", "10", "9:48.5710", "3", "0:57.3228*"], ["2", "42", "David Skillender", "David Skillender", "Holden VS Commodore", "6000", "10", "9:55.6866", "2", "0:57.9409"], ["3", "37", "Bruce Cook", "Bruce Cook", "Ford  Escort", "3759", "10", "9:56.4388", "4", "0:58.3359"], ["4", "18", "Troy Marinelli", "Troy Marinelli", "Nissan  Silvia", "3396", "10", "9:56.7758", "2", "0:58.4443"], ["5", "75", "Anthony Gilbertson", "Anthony Gilbertson", "BMW M3", "3200", "10", "10:02.5842", "3", "0:58.9336"], ["6", "26", "Trent Purcell", "Trent Purcell", "Mazda RX7", "2354", "10", "10:07.6285", "4", "0:59.0546"], ["7", "12", "Scott Hunter", "Scott Hunter", "Toyota  Corolla", "2000", "10", "10:11.3722", "5", "0:59.8921"], ["8", "91", "Graeme Wilkinson", "Graeme Wilkinson", "Ford  Escort", "2000", "10", "10:13.4114", "5", "1:00.2175"], ["9", "7", "Justin Wade", "Justin Wade", "BMW M3", "4000", "10", "10:18.2020", "9", "1:00.8969"], ["10", "55", "Greg Craig", "Grag Craig", "Toyota  Corolla", "1840", "10", "10:18.9956", "7", "1:00.7905"], ["11", "46", "Kyle Orgam-Moore", "Kyle Organ-Moore", "Holden VS Commodore", "6000", "10", "10:30.0179", "3", "1:01.6741"], ["12", "39", "Uptiles Strathpine", "Trent Spencer", "BMW Mini Cooper S", "1500", "10", "10:40.1436", "2", "1:02.2728"], ["13", "177", "Mark Hyde", "Mark Hyde", "Ford  Escort", "1993", "10", "10:49.5920", "2", "1:03.8069"], ["14", "34", "Peter Draheim", "Peter Draheim", "Mazda RX3", "2600", "10", "10:50.8159", "10", "1:03.4396"], ["15", "5", "Scott Douglas", "Scott Douglas", "Datsun  1200", "1998", "9", "9:48.7808", "3", "1:01.5371"], ["16", "72", "Paul Redman", "Paul Redman", "Ford  Focus", "2lt", "9", "10:11.3707", "2", "1:05.8729"], ["17", "8", "Matthew Speakman", "Matthew Speakman", "Toyota  Celica", "1600", "9", "10:16.3159", "3", "1:05.9117"], ["18", "74", "Lucas Easton", "Lucas Easton", "Toyota  Celica", "1600", "9", "10:16.8050", "6", "1:06.0748"], ["19", "77", "Dean Fuller", "Dean Fuller", "Mitsubishi  Sigma", "2600", "9", "10:25.2877", "3", "1:07.3991"], ["20", "16", "Brett Batterby", "Brett Batterby", "Toyota  Corolla", "1600", "9", "10:29.9127", "4", "1:07.8420"], ["21", "95", "Ross Hurford", "Ross Hurford", "Toyota  Corolla", "1600", "8", "9:57.5297", "2", "1:12.2672"], ["DNF", "13", "Charles Wright", "Charles Wright", "BMW 325i", "2700", "9", "9:47.9888", "7", "1:03.2808"], ["DNF", "20", "Shane Satchwell", "Shane Satchwell", "Datsun  1200 Coupe", "1998", "1", "1:05.9100", "1", "1:05.9100"]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how consistent the formatting is, you can probably use regex for this.

Here is a sample regex that works for the current data - may need to be tweaked depending on precise rules, but it gives the idea:

```
^

# Pos
(\d+|DNF)
\s+

#Car
(\d+)
\s+

# Team
([\w-]+(?: [\w-]+)+)
\s+

# Driver
([\w-]+(?: [\w-]+)+)
\s+

# Vehicle
([\w-]+(?:  ?[\w-]+)+)
\s+

# Cap
(\d{4}|\dlt)
\s+

# CL Laps
(\d+)
\s+

# Race.Time
(\d+:\d+\.\d+)
\s+

# Fastest Lap
(\d+)
\s+

# Fastest Lap Time
(\d+:\d+\.\d+\*?)
\s*

$
```

Comment: using regex on fixed width data is like hammering screws.

Answer (score 4):

If you can verify that the whitespace is space characters rather than tabs, and that overlong text is always truncated to fit the column structure, then I'd hard-code the slice boundaries:

```
parsed = [rawLine[0:3],rawLine[4:7],rawLine[9:38], ...etc... ]
```

Depending on the data source, this may be brittle (if, for instance every run has different column widths).

If the header row is always the same, you could extract the slice boundaries by searching for the known words of the header row.

Comment: "If the header row is always the same" -- you mean if the header is variable depending on the data widths?

Comment: @BobS - I think he means if the field names in the header row are always the same

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I gotchu:

**Edit**: I forgot to mention, its assuming you've stored your input text in the variable `input_string`

```
# Choose a delimeter that is unlikely to occure
DELIM = '|||'

# DRY -> extend String
class String
  def split_on_spaces(min_spaces = 1)
    self.strip.gsub(/\s{#{min_spaces},}/, DELIM).split(DELIM)
  end
end

# just get the data lines
lines = input_string.split("\n")
lines = lines[2...(lines.length - 4)].delete_if { |line|
  line.empty?
}

# Grab all the entries into a nice 2-d array
entries = lines.map { |line|
  [
    line[0..8].split_on_spaces,
    line[9..85].split_on_spaces(3).map{ |string| 
      string.gsub(/\s+/, ' ')  # replace whitespace with 1 space
    },
    line[85...line.length].split_on_spaces(2)

  ].flatten
}

# BONUS

# Make nice hashes
keys = [:pos, :car, :team, :driver, :vehicle, :cap, :cl_laps, :race_time, :fastest_lap]
objects = entries.map { |entry|
  Hash[keys.zip entry]
}
```

Outputs:

```
entries # =>
["1", "6", "Jason Clements", "Jason Clements", "BMW M3", "3200", "10", "9:48.5710", "3 0:57.3228*"]
["2", "42", "David Skillender", "David Skillender", "Holden VS Commodore", "6000", "10", "9:55.6866", "2 0:57.9409"]
...
# all of length 9, no extra spaces
```

And in case arrays just dont cut it

```
objects # =>
{:pos=>"1", :car=>"6", :team=>"Jason Clements", :driver=>"Jason Clements", :vehicle=>"BMW M3", :cap=>"3200", :cl_laps=>"10", :race_time=>"9:48.5710", :fastest_lap=>"3 0:57.3228*"}
{:pos=>"2", :car=>"42", :team=>"David Skillender", :driver=>"David Skillender", :vehicle=>"Holden VS Commodore", :cap=>"6000", :cl_laps=>"10", :race_time=>"9:55.6866", :fastest_lap=>"2 0:57.9409"}
...
```

I leave refactoring it into nice functions to you.

Comment: Thanks! But this is a little.. brittle. I have thousands of these files and unfortunately they vary slightly in the way they format things. I think an approach like Slither is best (defining templates).

Comment: yea I'd agree. Use a fixed-spacing / line size approach. I was just looking for an exercise

Answer (score 3):

Unless there's a clear rule on how the columns are separated, you can't really do it.

The approach you have is good, assuming you **know** that each column value is properly indented to the column title.

Another approach could be to group words that are separated by exactly one space together (from the text you provided, I can see that this rule also holds).

Comment: I don't think the one space rule holds in all cases: "Datsun  1200 Coupe" :( Silly user input.

Comment: Let's see, your answer seems to be that it cannot be done, while clearly it can be and quite easily really. So that's a problem. For me at least.

Comment: @pguardiario my answer says it can't be done "Unless there's a clear rule on how the columns are separated". Read again, from the top. The statement is true. It's just raw text.

Comment: I don't believe you need a clear rule, the rule can be interpolated from the data.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the text will always be spaced the same, you could split the string based on position, then strip away extra spaces around each part.  For example, in python:

```
pos=row[0:3].strip()
car=row[4:7].strip()
```

and so on. Alternately, you could define a regular expression to capture each part:

```
([:alnum:]+)\s([:num:]+)\s(([:alpha:]+ )+)\s(([:alpha:]+ )+)\s(([:alpha:]* )+)\s
```

and so on. (The exact syntax depends on your regexp grammar.) Note that the car regexp needs to handle the added spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to code this, but one way that definitely works for the above data set is by parsing it by white space and then assigning elements this way:

```
someArray = array of strings that were split by white space

Pos = someArray[0]
Car = someArray[1]
Competitor/Team = someArray[2] + " " + someArray[3]
Driver = someArray[4] + " " + someArray[5]
Vehicle = someArray[6] + " " + ... + " " + someArray[someArray.length - 6]
Cap = someArray[someArray.length - 5]
CL Laps = someArray[someArray.length - 4]
Race.Time = someArray[someArray.length - 3]
Fastest...Lap = someArray[someArray.length - 2] + " " + someArray[someArray.length - 1]
```

The vehicle part can be done by some sort of for or while loop.

Comment: This won't work. How do you parse "BMW 325i Sport" correctly, versus "Porsche 911". It doesn't account for strings with different spaces.

Comment: Actually it will work because that's the only part with a variable number of spaces.  That is why that part would be done by something like a for loop.  it will always start at 6 and end at the length of the array minus 6.  The way it works is that the length of the array changes based on how many elements are in the vehicle category